# How can I control braking system electronically?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, 8051

Is it possible to control the braking system and speed limiting of a car using a microcontroller? Please explain.

Comment: Are you sure you want to fiddle with you car's brakes? I know for a fact that I wouldn't.

Comment: *Real* car or RC car?

Answer (score 2):

They *are* being controlled by a microcontroller. Think of ABS for instance. This must be the part of the car where the most time and money was spent during development to get the **highest reliability**. You don't want to mess with that. Stay away from it.

Comment: stevenvh, I agree you have lots of experience in automobil wiring and electronics. So I expect a complete answer from you. I think he is asking how to sniff the CAN bus and take the control to his hand, something crazy like that.

Comment: Can u assist how to do that??

Comment: you want to hack CAN bus? stevenvh is the person , you probably hire him :P

Comment: A colleague of mine had a long dispute with the manufacturer of his car, which voided his warrantee because they thought he'd be tuning the car via the CAN bus (which he didn't). Anyway, they don't want any responsibility if you fiddle with it **because it's too dangerous!**

Comment: Hmmm ... brakes are on CAN bus aswell? The other day I saw a CAN Bluetooth receiver, this would mean I can make my car brake by scanning the correct QR tag from my mobile phone's cam! Or a making a gesture on it's screen, but that is too low tech ;o)

Comment: i want to control the speed of car via the microcontroller which will be connected to an ultrasonic meter at the other terminal.....

Comment: @jippie - AFAIK everything is on the CAN bus. Or *a* CAN bus, because they may have a separate bus for critical functions like the brakes. I'm not sure what you would need to control them though. Could be encrypted???

Comment: I'm so happy that my car has normal, hydraulic brakes and none of that "CAN bus" mess. I step on the pedal, the pressure gets amplified by engine vacuum (power brakes) and sent to the brakes. Simpler system means there are less parts to go wrong.

Comment: @Pentium100 - A few years ago Renault developed the Logan, which was targeted at the Asian market, where they often don't have service computers. For this reason the Logan was supposed to be an all mechanical car, no electronics. The European version, however, seems to be stuffed with things like ABS and AIRbags, perhaps under European regulations pressure. So far for an all mechanical car :-(

Comment: I'm not against electronics in a car (after all, my car has electronic ignition, probably containing two transistors), but do not like computers there. Everything gets very complicated because the manufacturers overuse the computers (computer control for turning lights, why?). And the attitude towards the owner becomes "he's an idiot, so let's make him go to the dealer for everything". I am learning how to repair my car so that I don't need to waste time going to the mechanic.

Comment: @Pentium - And the guys from the breakdown assistance service complain that they can's service a car anymore. All they can do is tow it to the next garage, because you need the service computer to know what's wrong.

Comment: I can see advantages in computer control. It's fine as long as it's tested and none of the primary functions can be prohibited. Also note that in your example, turning lights via computers, can be a cheaper and more reliable implementation. I believe there are some regulations in countries that force the car to put on warning lights when it makes an emergency stop. How convenient they don't have to use another relay or something, but can just send a message 'turn on warning lights'.

Comment: @Hans - Have you ever seen a single bugfree software? I haven't.

Comment: Nope. But a purely mechanical car can also fail. I mean that when the electrical systems are designed in way that most risks are assessed, I don't have any issues with it. Just tinkering with safety systems and brakes I find quite dangerous.

Comment: I don't know of any consumer automobile that is "brake by wire" -- my '99 VW Passat's accelerator is done completely electronically, but the steering and braking are still mechanical (with hydraulic assist). ABS is an add-on to the mechanical brakes which electronically releases brake pressure in rapid pulses to prevent the wheels from locking up, but it's still regular hydraulic brakes.

Comment: I love my new Wrangler, but one peeve I have is the turn signal has very noticeable jitter in the timing. It's really distracting... and professionally it just screams ugly compromise or possibly incompetence. You really want that kind of thing to be a theoretical mind game rather than regularly demonstrated in your personal transportation device.

Comment: Warning lights do not need another relay. The same blinker relay can be used, the switch just connects all four lamps in parallel.

@AndrewKohlsmith, my 1982 Mercedes W123 does not have computers, the gas pedal just opens the throttle valve, brakes are hydraulic etc. And yes, while a mechanical car can fail, it is easier to repair than a computer, besides, even computer controlled car needs to have the same mechanical components - throttle valve, brake calipers etc. The only computer in my car, though, is the MCU in the tape deck.

Answer (score 0):

There are several kind of breaks, modern cars are hybrid, and they extract 
kinetic energy and store it in batteries as electricity.

On trains, they have eddy current breakers. So it's quite possible to control
the breaking system using micro-controller.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake

If you talking about a RC car, then eddy current method is quite easy to implement.
Just simply short the motor terminals over a load.